# JBOSS7 won't load deployment structure xml

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I'm developing some App and at some point I already had code using xmlsec 1.4.3 but JBoss 7 loads by default xmlsec 1.5.1 so my code blows up. 
I've been reading through the documentation and ended here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-JBossDeploymentStructureFile

So, theoretically if I put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml on my WEB-INF folder (It is reading the XML because I failed writing properly the xsd and JBOSS crashed, and now without the xsd it says nothing) with this content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.santuario.xmlsec" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then I would be able to use my xmlsec 1.4.3 and the module of JBOSS would be disabled.

However this isn't working.

What I am missing here? This should work right?

Comment: How is your app packaged, WAR, EAR, etc?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It's a WAR. I added that ear-subdeployments tag just to try, but with or without that tag it does the same.

Comment: Could you specify which version of JBoss AS 7? I see nothing wrong with your XML.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It's 7.1.1.Final